# How to rank cells in a data frame in R WITHOUT adding it to the data frame

Tags: r

I've seen a lot of posts about how to add a rank column to the frame, but none on how to just make a variable, ranks, with the data from the ranking procedure. I figured, heck, why not just take the ranking function from inside the transform data.frame function and use that:

```
transform(df, 
          year.rank = ave(count, year, 
                          FUN = function(x) rank(-x, ties.method = "first")))
```

Buuuut that's trying to count occurrences in a year and thus isn't applicalbe to me. I just want to take the information from the cells in in the data frame and rank them. I'm trying to do the Kruskal-Wallis test, but use permutations to find the p-value (which `kruskal.test()` doesn't do).

I tried to just use `rank()` on my data frame, but I get this:

```
Week2_NoAnti   Week2_NaN3    Week2_TCS   Week2_EDTA         <NA>         <NA> 
       1            4            6           10           11           12 
    <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA>         <NA> 
       2            3            7            5            8            9
```

which is less than helpful. The data frame looks like this:

```
 Week2_NoAnti Week2_NaN3 Week2_TCS Week2_EDTA
1       0.0000     0.7665    0.0756     0.1060
2       0.0938     0.9222    0.0806     0.1289
3       0.1243     1.0109    0.1283     0.1882
```

As previously stated, I'd like to rank the cells. I will also need to later know which column they came from so I can average the ranks that each column got, so I can't just put them all into a vector and rank the vector.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Realized a better way to do the data frame might be to have one column with values, and another column with the label. Currently experiencing difficulty making the head() function show more than six results..., but here is what it shows:

```
       Groups agValues
1 Week2_NoAnti   0.0000
2 Week2_NoAnti   0.0938
3 Week2_NoAnti   0.1243
4   Week2_NaN3   0.7665
5   Week2_NaN3   0.9222
6   Week2_NaN3   1.0109
```

SOLUTION:

Sorry for wasting your time! The above organization made it much easier:

```
ranks = rank(agValues)
mean(ranks[Groups=="Week2_NoAnti"])
```

Comment: You want to rank within each column? and I assuming your groups would be NoAnti, NaN3, TCC, EDTA?

Comment: I want to rank across all columns. I figured a better way to do that was the edit I just added. Sorry, just had that thought and it makes my data into a format similar to a problem I saw in a textbook, hoping that makes it easy to transition their code over.

Comment: `head(x,n)` where n is number of rows to show, default is 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
rankmat=matrix(rank(as.vector(yourmatrix)),dim(yourmatrix))
```

Here you're transforming your matrix into a vector then taking the ranks and transforming the vector back into a matrix of correct dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

For the edited data frame that you just posted do this

```
ranked.df <-df[order(df$agValues),] #decreasing = FALSE by default 
#and df is your data.frame
```